# c# Sort a list of objects by a property of an object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Match objects:

```
IEnumerable<Match> matches
```

Match looks like this

```
    public class Match
    {
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_activity_date")]
    public string LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("messages")]
    public MatchMessage[] Messages { get; set; }

}
```

My MatchMessage class looks like this:

```
    public class MatchMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sent_date")]
    public string SentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to sort my list of Matches by the SentDate property in MatchMessage and I'm having a very hard time figuring this out.

i tried:

```
var newList = matchList.OrderBy(match => match.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.SentDate));
```

but I get an error when I do that. I've been googling for a while and can't find a solution to this.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will order `matchList` by Ascending order by the Latest Message of each match.

```
var newList = matchList.OrderBy(
        match =>
            match.Messages.Any()
            ? match.Messages.Max(x => DateTime.Parse(x.SentDate))
            : DateTime.MaxValue);
```

**Note:** Given SentDate is properly DateTime formatted.

Comment: When I run this I get an error: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @ygetarts, This is because one of the items in matchList didn't contain any messages, I've edited the code to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Your single `Match` may contain multiple messages, so there could be multiple `SendDate` for one`Match`.

To use SendDate from first message inside match:

```
var newList = matchList.OrderBy(match => match.Messages.FirstOrDefault()?.SendDate);
```

To use newest send date inside messages:

```
var newList = matchList.OrderBy(match => match.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.SendDate).FirstOrDefault()?.SendDate);
```

Warning: null-propagation from C# 6.0 used (only in VS 2015)

Comment: I'm using VS2013 so I modified this to be var newList = matchList.OrderBy(match => match.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.SentDate).FirstOrDefault()); However, this returns the same error I get when I run the query in my OP: At least one object must implement IComparable.